# Increment a number using POSIX features only?

Tags: ex-mode, posix

Of course in Vim you have `<C-a>` to increment a number.

Is this POSIX specified?

How can I increment (or decrement) a number portably, such as in a scripted edit with `ex`?

Even if the answer is just "Use an external filter," what would be the best POSIX-specified tool for this job?

---

Example specific requirement:

1. Increment the number found in the final field of line 1 by 1.
2. Decrement the number found in the final field of line 2 by 1.

Example input:

```
Here is    a    number: 5
Here is another number: 2
```

Example output:

```
Here is    a    number: 6
Here is another number: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`<C-a>` and `<C-x>` being normal mode commands, they are not really expected to work in `ex` which doesn't have normal mode. Furthermore, those commands are not defined in [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), either for `vi` or for `ex`.

As for a portable solution, you should probably write an `awk` script that would contain something like the following:

```
'{gsub( "number: \d", "number: " $5++ ); print }' foo
```

Comment: With the default FS, modifying a field will nuke the extra spaces seen in the original record, when the record is re-computed for output. You might be better off doing; `awk -F': ' 'NR == 1{$NF++} NR == 2{$NF--}1'`.